# Messages in Crashed Kafka Broker

Tags: apache-kafka, scalability, messagebroker

What happens to the messages that are successfully written to the leader partition on a Kafka Broker 1 and the Broker 1 crashes and comes up at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

If it's *successfully* written, then whenever the broker is up, any consumer subscribing to the topic, can consume the messages.
To quote the official doc:

> In distributed systems terminology we only attempt to handle a "fail/recover" model of failures where nodes suddenly cease working and then later recover (perhaps without knowing that they have died). Kafka does not handle so-called "Byzantine" failures in which nodes produce arbitrary or malicious responses (perhaps due to bugs or foul play).

In case you have multiple brokers, the leaders for the partitions are evenly distributed across brokers. More from the docs:

> We can now more precisely define that a message is considered committed when all in sync replicas for that partition have applied it to their log. Only committed messages are ever given out to the consumer. This means that the consumer need not worry about potentially seeing a message that could be lost if the leader fails. Producers, on the other hand, have the option of either waiting for the message to be committed or not, depending on their preference for tradeoff between latency and durability. This preference is controlled by the acks setting that the producer uses. Note that topics have a setting for the "minimum number" of in-sync replicas that is checked when the producer requests acknowledgment that a message has been written to the full set of in-sync replicas. If a less stringent acknowledgement is requested by the producer, then the message can be committed, and consumed, even if the number of in-sync replicas is lower than the minimum (e.g. it can be as low as just the leader).
>
> The guarantee that Kafka offers is that a committed message will not be lost, as long as there is at least one in sync replica alive, at all times.
>
> Kafka will remain available in the presence of node failures after a short fail-over period, but may not remain available in the presence of network partitions.

To understand how replication works in Kafka, please visit [this](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication) documentation.